# error FOR2614: assignment between arrays of differing rank

Tags: multidimensional-array, fortran

Hello guys I'm new at learn studying Fortran, but i need a help cause i got error

```
FOR2614: assignment between arrays of differing rank
```

when compiling my program. I'll left screenshot about what i write, i hope any of you can help me thanks.

```
REAL,INTENT(OUT)::BKL1(2,2),BKL2(2,2),BKL3(2,2),BKL4(2,2) 
  REAL,INTENT(OUT)::DX(2) 
REAL,DIMENSION(2)::DX1,DX2,DX3,DX4

DX1(1) = 0
DX1(2) = DX(1)

  DX2(1) = DX(1)
DX2(2) = DX(2)

  DX3(1) = DX(2)
DX3(2) = DX(3)

DX4(1) = DX(3)
DX4(2) = 0

FT1 = MATMUL(BKL1,DX1)
FT2 = MATMUL(BKL2,DX2)
FT3 = MATMUL(BKL3,DX3)
FT4 = MATMUL(BKL4,DX4)

WRITE(*,*)'GAYA DALAM BATANG 1'
WRITE(*,*) FT1

WRITE(*,*)'GAYA DALAM BATANG 2'
WRITE(*,*) FT2

WRITE(*,*)'GAYA DALAM BATANG 3'
WRITE(*,*) FT3

WRITE(*,*)'GAYA DALAM BATANG 4'
WRITE(*,*) FT4

RETURN
END
```

[image]

Comment: You should post complete code text.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You should never post code as a picture or screenshot. Always copy it and paste it **as text**. It is extremely important, see also [mcve].

Comment: Even though someone added the picture of your code, I repeat, it is necessary to post it **as text**. Not only it is unreadable without opening the picture in another window anyway (so adding it to the question in the edit makes little sense) but it is not searchable and we cannot copy the code for testing.

Answer (score 0):

> assignment between arrays of differing rank

You forgot to `DIMENSION(2)::FT1,FT2,FT3,FT4`.